# Document dataset for an R package

Tags: r, package, document

I am not sure how to ask this question. I am trying to generate a reference manual for my first package in `r`. The following code generated one `HTML` and one `MD` file.

```
library(Rd2md)
pkg_dir= "C:/Users/uqzwang/Desktop/chestr/chest"
out_dir = "C:/Users/uqzwang/Desktop/chestr/"
ReferenceManual(pkg = pkg_dir, outdir = out_dir)
```

However, all thing in data document are in one line like this:

A data frame with 2372 rows and 14 variables: list(“”, " “, list(list(”diabetes“), list(”diabetes status 1: with diabetes 0: without diabetes “)),”“,” “, list(list(”endpoint“), list(”mortality status 1: reached end point and 0 survived “)),”“,” “, ....

I thought I must have done something wrong with the following `data.R` file. I have tried to follow a template from http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html, but I still could not find the problem. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
#' Health outcomes of 2372 adults with and without diabetes
#'
#' A dataset containing diatetes status and mortality status of 2372 adults.
#'
#' @format A data frame with 2372 rows and 14 variables:
#'   \describe{
#'     \item{diabetes}{diabetes status 1 with diabetes 0 without diabetes}
#'     \item{endpoint}{mortality status 1 reached end point and 0 survived}
#'     \item{Age}{Age, in years}
#'     \item{sex}{sex, 1 male, 2 Female}
#'     \item{bmi}{Body mass index}
#'     \item{married}{marital status 1 married, 0 not}
#'     \item{smoke}{smoking status 1 smoker, 0 non-smoker}
#'     \item{cvd}{cardiovascular disease 1 yes 0 no}
#'     \item{cancer}{cancer 1 yes, 0 no}
#'     \item{education}{education 1 high, 0 low}
#'     \item{income}{income 1 high, 0 low}
#'     \item{t0}{time, age at the start of the follow-up}
#'     \item{t1}{time, age at the end of the follow-up}
#'     \item{mid_r}{matched set id, for conditional logistic regression}
#' }
#'
"diab_data"
```

**Edit**
The data Rd file:

```
% Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand
% Please edit documentation in R/data.R
\docType{data}
\name{diab_data}
\alias{diab_data}
\title{Health outcomes of 2372 adults with and without diabetes}
\format{A data frame with 2372 rows and 14 variables:
  \describe{
    \item{diabetes}{diabetes status 1 with diabetes 0 without diabetes}
    \item{endpoint}{mortality status 1 reached end point and 0 survived}
    \item{Age}{Age, in years}
    \item{sex}{sex, 1 male, 2 Female}
    \item{bmi}{Body mass index}
    \item{married}{marital status 1 married, 0 not}
    \item{smoke}{smoking status 1 smoker, 0 non-smoker}
    \item{cvd}{cardiovascular disease 1 yes 0 no}
    \item{cancer}{cancer 1 yes, 0 no}
    \item{education}{education 1 high, 0 low}
    \item{income}{income 1 high, 0 low}
    \item{t0}{time, age at the start of the follow-up}
    \item{t1}{time, age at the end of the follow-up}
    \item{mid_r}{matched set id, for conditional logistic regression}
}}
\usage{
diab_data
}
\description{
A dataset containing diatetes status and mortality status of 2372 adults.
}
\keyword{datasets}
```

I have tried to find a misplaced bracket or something but unsuccessful. Knitting the Rd file to RM shows the correct format. It is likely the problem is from 
`ReferenceManual(pkg = pkg_dir, outdir = out_dir)`

Comment: Can you show the corresponding Rd file?

Comment: @Roland, Sure. I am not sure one to show. There are several `R` files R directory and several `RD` files in `man` directories. `data.R` file is shown in OP. Thanks.

Comment: Also a Reference_Manual_chest.HTML file and a Reference_Manual_chest_md.MD file.

Comment: Open the data.Rd file in a text editor and check its content.You want to know which step the cause is: creating the Rd file from the R file or collating the Rd files for the manual or creating the MD file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Roland, I have added the data Rd file. The knitted file looks Ok.